# Is there a way to catch which subclasses invoked a method of the superclass in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, superclass, super

I'm writing a code where there is a super classes, called Soft_Constr, made in the following way:

```
def __init__(self, prop, name, static_init, static_lit, pred, kind):
    init_method ...

def evaluate_clause(self):
    code here
```

And there are some subclasses that may invoke the method 'evaluate_clause' defined in the superclass. Is there a way to catch which subclasses invoked the 'evaluate_clause' in Soft_Constr class?

```
def evaluate_clause(self):
    subclasses = method_to_get_subclasses(...)
```

Comment: `self.__class__`...?! – I'd like to cautiously ask *Why* though...

Answer (score 1):

This is an example for Python 2:

```
class SuperClass(object):
  def callername(self):
    print self.__class__.__name__

class ChildClass(SuperClass):
  def test(self):
    self.callername()

o = ChildClass()
o.test()
```

I used that a lot in the past to identify test classes for logging purposes. Very useful.

Not much different for Python 3:

```
class SuperClass():
  def callername(self):
    print(self.__class__.__name__)

class ChildClass(SuperClass):
  def test(self):
    self.callername()

o = ChildClass()
o.test()
```